# how to get selected object onclick of canvas?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento, fabricjs

I have shoe site which will have layers will be loaded image as canvas type. I need to get active layer id on click of canvas. I have tried with below code. but i am not getting current selected layer id. how to get it.

```
 function mouseClick(event){
  // var pointer = canvas.getPointer(event.e);
 // console.log(pointer.x);
 // console.log(pointer.y);
   //console.log(ob.get('componentId'));
 var curSelectedObjects = canvas.getActiveObject('src');
 console.log(curSelectedObjects);
 console.log(canvas.getActiveObject().get('type'));

 //canvas.forEachObject(function (ob) {

 //    var curSelectedObjects =              canvas.getActiveObject(ob.get('componentName'));
  //console.log(curSelectedObjects);
  //       
    //log('Given Position - ' + ob.get('position') + '; ' + 'Assigned     Position - ' + canvas.getObjects().indexOf(ob));
    //positionLog(ob.get('componentName') + ' - ' + ob.get('degree') +' : ' + ob.get('position') + '; ' + 'Assigned Position - ' +   canvas.getObjects().indexOf(ob));
    //log(ob);
  // });

      //  canvas.forEachObject(function (ob) {
//            if (ob.get('degree') == angle) {
  //                console.log(ob.get('componentId'));
 //               // ob.opacity = 0.3;
//                //if (ob.get('componentId') == 'C_'+cId) {
 ////                    ob.opacity = 1;
  ////                }
//            }
//        });
    }
```

Comment: where do you register the event? can you post a fiddle with the situation? do you click on objects or outside objects?

Comment: clicking on inside the object

Answer (score -1):

```
canvas.on('mouse:down', function(e) {

    if (e.target
```

Comment: Can you explain this a bit further to turn it into a useful answer?

Comment: subscribe to fabric canvas mouse down event. it will have clicked fabric object as target if any

Comment: looks like OP is using own click event handler then trying to iterate though objects looking for selected state. that approach is not necessary with above

Comment: Do you have custom jquery shoe design tool so that i can use it my site